# apache configured but still website not loading coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I had the apache configured through web configuration tool. my coldfusion is installed on port 9000, but i want my websites to be run under apache,

so I followed the steps, created the webconfig in the coldfusion folder and matched the ports, in the httpd-vhosts.conf file

i wrote this

```
<VirtualHost *:8085>
    DocumentRoot "C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/project1"
    ServerName test-host.corp.adobe.com
    ServerAlias www.test-host.corp.adobe.com
    ErrorLog "logs/test-host.corp.adobe.com.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test-host.corp.adobe.com.log" common 
    JkMountFile "C:\ColdFusion11\config\wsconfig\1\uriworkermap.properties"
</VirtualHost>
```

i have xampp, so apache is configured on port 8085

but when i browse the website as:

`test-host.corp.adobe.com` or `test-host.corp.adobe.com:8085`, the page does not load, i tried restarting but no luck

Comment: Doesn't `.hosts` have to be changed too?

Comment: IMO, your local server name shouldn't be related to an existing `.com` unless you have code that's looking for a specific domain name (and yes, I've dealt with that). You need to add your local server's host name to your local `hosts` file so that Apache can resolve the domain name to your local server.

Comment: Can you get to `127.0.0.1:8085` ?

Comment: yes, i can. i did many changes and installed wamp server and did a manual connector of 64 bits and it is working. but now i am getting 503 unavaliable when i browse the website using apache virtualhost saying: mysite,site:8087/index.cfm